# How to empty trash on boot partition

Tags: boot, partition, trash

I had deleted some old kernels a while back to make space on my boot partition (using elementary os), but now I realize they went into the trash-0/files folder on the boot, I tried opening sudo pantheon-files and deleting them manually but it doesn't work, I get this error:

[Gtk] gtk_application_uninhibit: assertion 'cookie > 0' failed
Files will not function properly.

I really need to get rid of these files as I need the space for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line:

```
$ sudo rm /boot/.Trash-1000/*
```

would empty all the files from the trash.  The 1000 refers to your UID so may differ.  It will begin with `.Trash-` though.  There are two directories within this one - one called `files` where your deleted files reside and another called `info` which stores small text files containing the original filename and the deletion date.  As you're planning to delete all the files permanently then you can also delete the `info` directory.

Note that these kernels should be removed automatically when you remove the specific package with `apt-get` (or whatever you use to install/remove packages).

Try:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

which should remove all packages (not just kernels) that aren't in use.

If you don't want to use `autoremove` in-case it removes too much, then `ubuntu-tweak` can remove them for you.

Comment: I tried sudo rm /boot/trash-0/files/* but it says no such file or directory, no idea why.

Comment: I also tried the autoremove but that doesn't delete the stuff in trash which I really need to get rid of.

Comment: I've just checked my system and found I had `nemo` installed. The location is a hidden _dot_ directory called `.Trash-1000`.  I'll edit the answer.